# Australia transit visas dates

Tags: visas, australia, transit-visas

Australian visa 2-part question:

1. Does one get if for certain dates or a period of time?
2. Is it possible to change the dates or there is a need to issue a new one in case the flight dates are changed?

P.S. Please do not refer me to gov.au.whatever, there is no answer for those questions on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking about the [Transit (subclass 771)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-) visa.  You will find the actual regulations on this visa in Part 771 of Schedule 2 to the [Migration Regulations 1994](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2017C00350/Html/Volume_2#_Toc480381868).

> 1. Does one get if for certain dates or a period of time?

The visa will specify a date on or before which you must enter Australia.  Once you enter, you may remain for up to 72 hours (clauses 771.611 and 771.511).

> 2. Is it possible to change the dates or there is a need to issue a new one in case the flight dates are changed?

Once a visa has been granted, it cannot be varied.  If your flight times have changed, you will need to apply for a new visa.